# CoreMidi - How to transpose a track of midifile?

Tags: transpose, coremidi

I am studying coremidi and trying just few experiments
I am wondering how to make a transpose in semitones of a miditrack of a midifile.
Can someone show me how to do it?

thank so much

Comment: Your question should be much more specific. A midi file is, at a high level, "just" a sequence of note-on/note-off midi messages (+ loads of bells and whistles ;) Transposing only means shifting the midi note part of the midi message by 1 (or more) up or down and pairing the note-on with the note-off, so that you can actually stop the note you just started playing.

Comment: Thank for your comment. What I meant is to have the choice to transpose for example all or every Channel track:
for example you may have 16 track for each 16 channels
I might want to transpose track 1 or 2 o 6 all of them
Is there a simple way?
Thank so much in advance

Comment: Which API? Are you using MIDINoteMessage, MusicTrack, and MusicSequence? Or, are you using MIDIPacketList?

Answer (score 0):

CoreMIDI does nothing with MIDI files.

You'll have to parse the MIDI file until the desired track chunk is encountered and apply a transposition offset to the note number of each Note On/Off message (including running status).